# Why did Borra say, "If only Conall could see you"?

Tags: maleficent-mistress-of-evil

In Maleficent: Mistress of Evil (2019), before Queen Aurora asked her to walk down the aisle, Maleficent was approached by Borra:

> Borra: **If only Conall could see you**.
>
> Maleficent: Borra...it's time to come home.

Why did Borra say, "If only Conall could see you"?

Comment: You might want to see the movie in your native language instead of english. Three of  your four questions on this topic seems to be motivated of a lack of knowledge in english, not by something related to the movie itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borra and Conall both believed that Maleficents would be the end to the war between fairies and humans. Borra believed it would be through violence and bloodshed resulting in the end of the human kingdoms while Conall believed she would bring peace between the two peoples.

Eventually the later happened, proving Borra wrong and Conall right, sadly Conall never lived to see his hopes come true. With Borra being both sad for his friends loss and proud of Maleficents achievements.